# Keycloak user-federation

Tags: keycloak-rest-api

I used keycloak for securing my web app project, the first scenario was keycloak with database user, I have created many roles and groups, and I can manage all these  (users, roles, groups) from my app using keycloak api, till here everything works fine.
then the 2end scenario comes with user federation (from Active Directory AD), so I have delegated the authentication to AD with edit mode = Readonly and Import Users = on.  The user synch works fine, even for the user changes, wherease I can't manage the roles , groups using keycloak Rest API and can't assigned the default role for any user right after the synchronization. how could I do that?
any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: as a consequence of using keycloak with AD users , I could't retreive the users list from keycloak api on my third client.    ` return this.http.get<User[]>(this.baseURL.url + 'admin/realms/' + this.baseURL.realm + '/users');` any help

Answer (score 0):

After the sync, you can user [LDAP mappers](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_ldap_mappers) to assign roles/groups to users.